# How to identifying Response MIME type in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs4, extjs

I am struggling to differentiate the response MIME type in sencha touch. My login service is designed in such a way that if the login success then it will give me a JSON object. If it failed to authenticate, then it will return a plan error text. 
How can i find the difference? My request looks like this.

```
    Ext.Ajax.request({
              url : 'http://xxxx.com/Sencha/LoginServlet?userid='+ agentid + "&password=" + password,                     
              type:'json',           
              success : function(response, opt) {
                  alert("response text" + response.responseText);
                  var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                  console.dir(obj); 
                  App.views.viewport.reveal('nextScreen');  
          },

            failure : function(response, opt) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', response.responseText);
            }

          });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ext JS internally uses the XMLHttpRequest Object, so the reponse is w3 consortium compliant. Hence you can retrieve the response object properties like in normal javascript. Example :

```
response.getResponseHeader("Content-Type")
```

For details on how to retrieve other details from the response object see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#response).